# How to read data by portions in Vaadin for export to PDF

Tags: java, java-stream, vaadin

I have 2 billion records in MySQL.

I use Vaadin Framework with Lazy Loading (https://vaadin.com/docs/v23/components/grid#lazy-loading) and filter (with callback):

```
private void showData(Filter filter) {
        positionGrid.setItems(query -> {
            var vaadinSortOrders = query.getSortOrders();
            var springSortOrders = new ArrayList<Sort.Order>();
            for (QuerySortOrder so : vaadinSortOrders) {
                String colKey = so.getSorted();
                if (so.getDirection() == SortDirection.ASCENDING) {
                    springSortOrders.add(Sort.Order.asc(colKey));
                } else if (so.getDirection() == SortDirection.DESCENDING) {
                    springSortOrders.add(Sort.Order.desc(colKey));
                }
            }
            return positionService.getAll(
                    filter,
                    PageRequest.of(query.getPage(),
                            query.getPageSize(),
                            Sort.by(springSortOrders))
            ).stream();
        });
    }
```

I need export data in PDF report (I use itextpdf library). But I get an error:

**java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**

My code:

```
private final PositionGrid positionGrid;
```

...

```
positionGrid.getLazyDataView().getItems().forEach(elem -> {
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(num.incrementAndGet())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getSsi().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(PositionGrid.formatter.format(elem.getDatetime())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getPosx().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getPosy().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getVelocity() != null) ? elem.getVelocity().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getRssi() != null) ? elem.getRssi().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getPathDelay() != null) ? elem.getPathDelay().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            table.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getBsId() != null) ? elem.getBsId().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
        });
```

Tell me please. How do I read the data in parts (I need write it to a PDF file)?

This is my Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Positions")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Position {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "datetime", nullable = false)
    private Instant datetime;

    @Column(name = "posx", nullable = false)
    private Double posx;

    @Column(name = "posy", nullable = false)
    private Double posy;

    @Column(name = "velocity")
    private Double velocity;

    @Column(name = "rssi")
    private Short rssi;

    @Column(name = "pathDelay")
    private Short pathDelay;

    @Column(name = "bs_id")
    private Integer bsId;

    @Column(name = "ssi", nullable = false)
    private Long ssi;
}
```

Comment: Do you also get the OOME, if you do _nothing_ inside the `forEach`?

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Comment: K.Nicholas, hello. I write I wrote my question in more detail.

Comment: Cfrick, thank you. I try it:

An empty method  OOMEpositionGrid.getLazyDataView().getItems().forEach   does not give an error

Comment: I have removed the Vaadin tag and I suggest you turn this question into a question on how "stream" writing out the PDF with whatever library you are using.

Comment: Sorry. As it turned out, I checked on 100 thousand records. In this case, there were no errors. But with the number of over 100 thousand records  get OOME ( It turns out that this problem concerns Vaadin. Namely, how can I get data in parts for writing to a PDF file from Grid table....

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Eliminate Vaadin, use a scrolling resultset directly from your DB.

Comment: I have a web application with vaadin. I have a page with reports. These page use filters. Vaadin has Lazy Loading. This allows you to display a limited number of records in the page. So I have a beautiful report on the site. But it was necessary to upload the report to a pdf file. Based on your words, it turns out that it is necessary to write other functionality, ignoring all the features of Lazy Loading Vaadin. This is probably the only solution, but it's very sad :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks cfrick for help.

I have nice report by my page and I used Lazy Loading with filter and API Criteria:

My method:

```
positionService.getAll(
                    filter,
                    PageRequest.of(query.getPage(),
                            query.getPageSize(),
                            Sort.by(springSortOrders))
            ).stream();
```

My service:

```
@Service
public class PositionCustomService extends CustomService<Position> {

    private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(PositionCustomService.class);

    private final PositionRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public PositionCustomService(PositionRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Page<Position> getAll(PageRequest pageRequest) {
        return repository.findAll(pageRequest);
    }

    public List<Position> getAll(Filter filter) {
        return repository.findAll(bySearchWithFilter(filter, Position.class));
    }

    public Page<Position> getAll(Filter filter, PageRequest pageRequest) {
        return repository.findAll(bySearchWithFilter(filter, Position.class), pageRequest);
    }

    public Map<LocalDate, Long> getCountByDays(int days) {
        return repository.countByDays(days);
    }
}
```

My CustomService:

```
public abstract class CustomService<T> {

    public static <T> Specification<T> bySearchWithFilter(Filter filter, Class<T> clazz) {

        return (Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criterailBuilder) -> {

            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

            // Add Predicates for tables to be joined
            List<JoinColumnProps> joinColumnProps = filter.getJoinColumnProps();

            if (joinColumnProps != null && !joinColumnProps.isEmpty()) {
                for (JoinColumnProps joinColumnProp : joinColumnProps) {
                    addJoinColumnProps(predicates, joinColumnProp, criterailBuilder, root);
                }
            }

            List<AttributeFilter> attributeFilters = filter.getAttributeFilters();

            if (attributeFilters != null && !attributeFilters.isEmpty()) {

                for (final AttributeFilter attributeFilter : attributeFilters) {
                    addPredicates(predicates, attributeFilter, criterailBuilder, root);
                }
            }

            if (predicates.isEmpty()) {
                return criterailBuilder.conjunction();
            }

            return criterailBuilder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
        };
    }

    private static <T> void addJoinColumnProps(List<Predicate> predicates, JoinColumnProps joinColumnProp,
                                               CriteriaBuilder criterailBuilder, Root<T> root) {

        AttributeFilter attributeFilter = joinColumnProp.getSearchAttrFilter();
        Join<Object, Object> joinParent = root.join(joinColumnProp.getJoinColumnName());

        String property = attributeFilter.getField().getNameField();
        Path expression = joinParent.get(property);

        addPredicate(predicates, attributeFilter, criterailBuilder, expression);
    }

    private static <T> void addPredicates(List<Predicate> predicates, AttributeFilter attributeFilter,
                                          CriteriaBuilder criterailBuilder, Root<T> root) {
        String property = attributeFilter.getField().getNameField();
        Path expression = root.get(property);

        addPredicate(predicates, attributeFilter, criterailBuilder, expression);
    }

    private static void addPredicate(List<Predicate> predicates, AttributeFilter attributeFilter,
                                     CriteriaBuilder criterailBuilder, Path expression) {
        switch (attributeFilter.getOperator()) {
            case "=":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.equal(expression, attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "LIKE":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.like(expression, "%" + attributeFilter.getValue() + "%"));
                break;
            case "IN":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.in(expression).value(attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case ">":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.greaterThan(expression, (Comparable) attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "<":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.lessThan(expression, (Comparable) attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case ">=":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(expression, (Comparable) attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "<=":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(expression, (Comparable) attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "!":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.notEqual(expression, attributeFilter.getValue()));
                break;
            case "IsNull":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.isNull(expression));
                break;
            case "NotNull":
                predicates.add(criterailBuilder.isNotNull(expression));
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(attributeFilter.getOperator() + " is not a valid predicate");
        }
    }
}
```

My repo:

```
    @Repository
    public interface PositionRepository extends JpaRepository<Position, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Position>, PositionRepositoryCustom {
    }


    @Repository
    public interface PositionRepositoryCustom {
    
        Map<LocalDate, Long> countByDays(int days);
    }

public class PositionRepositoryImpl implements PositionRepositoryCustom {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public Map<LocalDate, Long> countByDays(int days) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery cq = cb.createQuery();

        Root<Position> position = cq.from(Position.class);
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        Instant endDate = Instant.now();
        Instant startDate = endDate.minus(days, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);

        Expression dateWithoutTimeExp = cb.function("date", Instant.class, position.get(PositionModelFilter.MESSAGE_DATE.getNameField()));

        cq.multiselect(dateWithoutTimeExp, cb.count(position.get(PositionModelFilter.ID.getNameField())));

        cq.groupBy(dateWithoutTimeExp);

        predicates.add(cb.between(position.get(PositionModelFilter.MESSAGE_DATE.getNameField()),
                startDate, endDate));
        cq.where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));

        Map<LocalDate, Long> resMap = new HashMap<>();
        entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList().forEach(elem -> {
            Object[] mas = (Object[])elem;
            resMap.put(((Date)mas[0]).toLocalDate(), (long)mas[1]);
        });

        return resMap;
    }
}

public interface JpaSpecificationExecutor<T> {
    Optional<T> findOne(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);

    List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);

    Page<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);

    List<T> findAll(@Nullable Specification<T> spec, Sort sort);

    long count(@Nullable Specification<T> spec);

    boolean exists(Specification<T> spec);
}
```

I found the only solution to how to work with big data: I started making several limited queries:

```
int index = 0;
        int limit = 10_000;

        while (true) {
            log.debug("Загружается партия записей: " + index);
            List<Position> res = positionService.getAll(
                            positionFilterView.getFilter(),
                            PageRequest.of(index,
                                    limit,
                                    Sort.by(Sort.Order.asc("datetime")))
                    ).stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

            if (res.isEmpty()) break;

            Table dataTable = new Table(UnitValue.createPercentArray(columnWidths));
            res.forEach(elem -> {
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(String.valueOf(num.incrementAndGet())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getSsi().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(PositionGrid.formatter.format(elem.getDatetime())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER)));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getPosx().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph(elem.getPosy().toString())).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getVelocity() != null) ? elem.getVelocity().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getRssi() != null) ? elem.getRssi().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getPathDelay() != null) ? elem.getPathDelay().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
                dataTable.addCell(new Cell().setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER).add(new Paragraph((elem.getBsId() != null) ? elem.getBsId().toString() : "")).setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.CENTER));
            });

            pdfExporter.getDocument().add(dataTable);
            //pdfExporter.getDocument().flush();

            index++;
        }
```

The only problem is that 10 thousand records are written to the file in 1 minute. It's a very long time (